# Saving a photo from photo library

Tags: save, nsuserdefaults, photo, photolibrary

I have some part of application that save user data like name, address and photo. I have solve problem to take a photo from photo library.
Because that's only small database, I use NSUserDefaults to save data.
But I don't know how to save photo from photo library that I put in UIImageView...
Please give me some help..
Is it possible to use NSUserDefaults to save that photo??

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using NSUserDefaults to store the image name rather than the data. You should be able to retrieve the image from the photo library no problem as long as you have the filename you need.